# reverse proxy nginx docker django

Tags: django, docker, nginx

so what I'm trying to do is to have two web apps: appli1 and appli2.

When i access from the browser to x.x.x.x:8000 i get the appli1 working good, but with x.x.x.x:8001 i don't get appli2 but I get again appli1. so how can I have this working correctly ?

here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8001:8001
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    #ports: 
      #- "8000:8000"
  web2:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
volumes:  
  redis_data:
```

and here is my nginx.conf file :

```
events {

}

http {
  server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name web.appli1.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 8001;
    server_name web2.appli2.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://web2:8001;
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
CMD . /app/djangodocker/
```

I've also  set the domains in /etc/hosts using ip of host machine

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Please add your Dockerfiles

Comment: i've edited and added the dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  nginx:
     image: nginx:latest
     container_name: ngnix-proxy
     ports:
       - 8000:8000
     volumes:
       - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
     depends_on:
       - web
       - web2
```

---

```
server {
  listen 8000;
  root /srv/www/static;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @web @web2;
  }

  location @web {
    proxy_pass http://web:8000;
  }

  location @web2 {
    proxy_pass http://web2:8001;
  }
}
```